# Anylogic PLE in batch mode

Tags: java, eclipse, anylogic

I installed Anylogic 8.2.3 on a Linux server, but I got these warnings and the interface didn't come out. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
Do you agree to the above license terms? [yes or no]
yes
Cleaning AnyLogic Workspace...
Extracting archive...
Unpacking archive...
AnyLogic is now unpacked into
/home/s/sdaza/anylogic
directory and ready to run.

Desktop shortcut "/home/s/sdaza/Desktop/AnyLogic (3).desktop" created.
Please run AnyLogic to proceed to product activation.

> ./anylogic/anylogic
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler (file:/home/s/sdaza/anylogic/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.13.0.v20170609-0707.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy.getEncoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/s/sdaza/anylogic/release
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: What Linux do you have? Is it headless server or does it have GUI toolkit (which one)?

Comment: It is a CLI-only system. I can use the terminal emulator of my choice to access to it.

Comment: AnyLogic needs system with GUI. You may find the detailed info at the bottom of the download page: https://www.anylogic.com/downloads/

Comment: You may execute the exported models at the systems without GUI, for this purpose create and export Custom experiment

Comment: I cannot do that with the PLE version. It is weird, it was working with the version 7.

Comment: that is strange. What is the full version - 7.x.x?

Comment: It was PLE 7.2. I run the app and I got an interface to run my regular experiments (similar to my desktop version)